# createName error for XLConnect in R

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am getting a new error while using XLConnect.  I'm currently using R 2.15.0 and XLConnect 0.2-5. I get the following error while using the example from the package documentation for createName:
*Error in UseMethod("createName") : 
  no applicable method for 'createName' applied to an object of class "workbook"*

```
# Load workbook (create if not existing)
wb <- loadWorkbook("autofilter.xlsx", create = TRUE)
# Create a worksheet named ’mtcars’
createSheet(wb, name = "mtcars")
# Create a named region called ’mtcars’ on the sheet called ’mtcars’
createName(wb, name = "mtcars", formula = "mtcars!$A$1")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't get this error on R 3.0.0 and XLConnect 0.2-5. You should probably notify the package author, but they will probably simply tell you to upgrade R.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my end with R 2.15.0, 2.15.2, 3.0.0. What is your sessionInfo()? Did you install XLConnect from CRAN - binary or source?

Comment: Martin, thanks for your quick reply.  This is not an issue with XLConnect.  R.oo also has a function createName().

Comment: I can load both packages at the same time with no issues if R.oo is loaded before XLConnect.  R.oo has a namespace, so this order prevents conflicts.